# Concepts: require a function on a type without default constructing that type

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I need to require of some type A that there exists a function f(A, A::B).

I'm testing that by calling f with instances of A and A::B. Is there a less ostentatious way to test against an instance of the dependent type without requiring default constructible?

```cpp
template <class Container>
concept CanPutData = requires (Container a)
{
  //put(typename Container::data_type{}, a);  // overconstrained
  put(*reinterpret_cast<typename Container::data_type*>(0), a); // oof
};

void test(CanPutData auto container) {}

template<class Container>
void put(typename Container::data_type const& data, Container& into) {}


template<class Data>
struct data_container { using data_type = Data; };
struct not_default_constructible_data { int& v; };

int main()
{
  test(data_container<not_default_constructible_data>{});

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might be interested in std::declval

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same way you're already getting a `Container` without requiring that one to be default constructible: by just sticking it in the parameter list of the requires expression:

```cpp
template <class Container>
concept CanPutData = requires (Container container, typename Container::data_type data)
{
  put(data, container);
};
```

Comment: Would it be a good idea to check the `typename Container::data_type` before putting it as a parameter in the requires expression? Or will that check work itself out?

Comment: @NicolBolas https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.req#general-5

Comment: That seems to say that you need to check it manually. It says,"The substitution of template arguments into a requires-expression may result in the formation of invalid types or expressions in its requirements or the violation of the semantic constraints of those requirements." The parameter declaration is not part of the "requirement" grammar, so it doesn't count.

Comment: @NicolBolas Wording issue then, I think the intent is pretty clear, and all implementations do the same thing.

Comment: @Barry What if the member is not the "direct whole" parameter declaration? For example, is `requires (std::vector<typename T::Member> vec)` well-formed for `T=int` ？

Comment: @VainMan Yeah that's just as invalid a type - it doesn't matter how the invalidity comes about.

Answer (score 0):

You can also put `Container::data_type` in the template parameter list

```
template <class Container, class DataType = Container::data_type>
concept CanPutData = requires (DataType d, Container a)
{
  put(d, a);
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4PWG9vP1W)

The advantage of this form is that when the `requires`-clause is relatively large, if the `Container` does not have a `data_type` member, the compiler will only report that the template parameter list does not satisfy the constraints, [rather than output the entire requires clause](https://godbolt.org/z/e6cKq3zoo).

Comment: What if you don't want to get a compiler error message *at all*? What if you want `CanPutData` to resolve to `false` if `Container` doesn't have a `data_type`?

Comment: "*What if you want CanPutData to resolve to false if Container doesn't have a data_type?*" In such case the compiler will clearly report error: `no type named 'data_type' in 'struct Container'`. I don't quite understand what you mean?

Comment: The point of using a concept is that you *do not want* compile errors. If the requirements of a concept are not fulfilled, then the concept should resolve to `false` and any other alternative templates should be able to be used. You only get a compile error if there are no viable alternative constraints. If you just want compile errors, then you don't need to have a concept at all; just try to use expressions and someone will get an error if their type doesn't provide that functionality.

Comment: "*If you just want compile errors, then you don't need to have a concept at all*" You cannot avoid compiler errors. In this case, I *do* want clear compile errors to tell me why the type doesn't satisfy the constraints.

Comment: I am using concepts largely just to clean up compiler errors; is that not common?